# Is this trick not true when solving an ODE?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a difficult first-order differential equation to solve. Here it is
$$-y'^2y^2+ay^4+by=-c$$
Where y is a function of time and a,b and c are constants.

So in order to find an easier differential equation that I could solve I did the following, we know that

$$1=\frac{dt}{dt}=\frac{dt}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dt}{dy}y'$$

Let's thus rewrite the ODE as,
$$-y'^2y^2+ay^4+by=-c\frac{dt}{dy}y'$$
Since I know that $y'$ is never 0, I divide by $y'$ on both sides,
$$(-y'y^2+\frac{a}{y'}y^4+\frac{b}{y'}y)dy=-c\times dt$$
So if we integrate both sides with respect to the correct variable we get,
$$\int(-y'y^2+\frac{a}{y'}y^4+\frac{b}{y'}y)dy=\int-c\times dt$$
$$-\frac{y'}{3}y^3+\frac{a}{5y'}y^5+\frac{b}{2y'}y^2=-c\times t+p$$
Where p is an integration constant. This puts me in a more favorable place for solving my original problem. Is the trick used in equation 3 valid? Are there any errors?

Comment: The manipulation is correct, but the integration is not: $y'$ is not a constant with respect to $dy$.

Comment: @Miguel so what would be the correct integration? Or does it depend on the expression of y'?

Comment: @stanisverylow you can't integrate it without already knowing how $y'$ depends on $y$ - similar to how $\int y(x) dx$ can't be evaluated without knowing what $y(x)$ is in terms of $x$ (since the answer clearly depends on if $y(x) = x$ or if $y(x) = x^{2}$ for example).

Answer (score 3):

$$-\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2y^2+ay^4+by=-c$$
This is a separable ODE.
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\pm \frac{1}{y}\sqrt{ay^4+by+c}$$
$$dt=\pm\frac{y\:dy}{\sqrt{ay^4+by+c}}$$
$$t=\pm\int \frac{y\:dy}{\sqrt{ay^4+by+c}}+\text{constant}$$
The integral can be expressed on closed form thanks to some standard functions referenced as "elliptic integrals" of first, second and/or third kind. The function $t(y)$ is awfully complicated because one have first to solve a polynomial equation of fourth degree : $ay^4+by+c=a(y-A)(y-B)(y-C)(y-D)$ for $A,B,C,D$ as functions of $a,b,c$.

This would leads to an explicite function $t(y)$.

Then comes the main difficulty : To inverse the function $t(y)$ for $y(t)$. I guess that $y(t)$ cannot be expressed in terms of a finite number of standard functions.

Note : I suspect a typo in the wording of the question. If the original ODE was with $by^2$ instead of $by$ the solving would be at a level far below.